# VideoCapture.read() returns past image

Tags: image, opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm running `python3.6` with `openCV` on the `Raspberry pi`(OS is `Raspbian`)

The approximate structure of the code is as follows.

1. The `image` is captured at time interval(3~5 min).
2. Captured `image` is processed in functions and returns measure(kind of accuracy)
3. Iterate 1.~2. until `end_check()` returns `True`

Problem is that the most recent taken `image` is out of date. It looks it was taken almost 10 minutes ago. All images recently taken are late. But the `images` taken at the beginning seem to be timed. And the time recorded in all `.jpg` files entered correctly
+It looks this problem is occured after more than a hour. (20~22 iterates)

`Images` are captured with `cam0.read()` in the `cv2` package. Below is main part of the code. It is quite long to upload full code. It someone request, I will update.

```
def run(interval,model_list):
    cam0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  #Only cam0 is used. cam2 is just to record.
    camdir = "/home/pi/capstone/cam0/"
    cam2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    cam2dir = "/home/pi/capstone/cam2/"
    runNo = 0
    acc_list = list()
    error_list = list()
    end = False
    while(end == False):
        print(runNo,"th run")

        img_name = "%s.jpg" %runNo
        frame, res = cam0.read()   #`res` is the image which will be processed
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(camdir,img_name),res)
        _ , cam2pic = cam2.read()
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(cam2dir,img_name),cam2pic)
        try:
            temp = Real(res)
            mat = temp.match(model_list)
            acc_list.append([mat,runNo])
            print("Accuracy=", mat)
        except ValueError:
            acc_list.append(["ValueError",runNo])
            error_list.append(["ValueError",runNo])
        except AttributeError:
            acc_list.append(["AttributeError", runNo])
            error_list.append(["AttributeError",runNo])
        except SmallObjectError:
            acc_list.append(["SmallObjectError", runNo])
            error_list.append(["SmallObjectError",runNo])
        runNo = runNo+1
        endNo = 40
        if(runNo/2 > endNo):
            end_check(res, end)
        elif(runNo > endNo):
            end = True
        sleep(interval*60)

    with open("acc_list.txt", "w") as output: #records for tracking errors
        output.write(str(acc_list))
    with open("err_list.txt", "w") as output:
        output.write(str(error_list))
    cam0.release()
    cam2.release()

run(3.5,model_list)
```

(+) Some newly found things and guess

- The `images` time gap is getting bigger with code running
- Code finally showed `OpenCV Error`
- It looks kind of `Video signal` is stored in RAM on `R-pi` and `.read()` returning out-dated `image` in `RAM`
- Stored `Video signal` in `RAM` araise resource problem

Below is the `OpenCV Error`

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dsize.area() > 0 || (inv_scale_x > 0 && inv_scale_y > 0)) in resize, file /home/pi/opencv/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp, line 4045
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runpi.py", line 264, in <module>
    run(3.5,model_list)
  File "runpi.py", line 234, in run
    mat = temp.match(model_list)
  File "runpi.py", line 184, in match
    self.__resize(model.get_m_inform())
  File "runpi.py", line 147, in __resize
    self.mask = cv2.resize(self.mask, None, fx=reratio, fy=reratio, interpolation = inter_method)
cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv/opencv-3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:4045: error: (-215) dsize.area() > 0 || (inv_scale_x > 0 && inv_scale_y > 0) in function resize
```

(+) Some part of code araising Error

This is `__.resize()` method. When I process the `image` that occured `OpenCV Error` manually, it works well even if `OpenCV Error` pointing out kind of `image` size matter. So I thought it is not matter of `image` itself or `size` got from `md_inf()`. Anyway Here is code.

```
def __resize(self, md_inf):       
    #md_inf = [219, 122, 132, 171, 262] <-sample
    reratio = md_inf[0]/self.y
    if(reratio>1):
        inter_method = cv2.INTER_LINEAR
    else:
        inter_method = cv2.INTER_AREA

    ###below is line 147###
    self.mask = cv2.resize(self.mask, None, fx=reratio, fy=reratio, interpolation = inter_method)
    temp = np.zeros((md_inf[3], md_inf[4]), np.uint8)
    m_cx, m_cy = md_inf[1:3]

    _, contour, _ = cv2.findContours(self.mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    total_contour = contour[0]
    for ctr in contour[1:]:
        total_contour = np.concatenate((total_contour, ctr), axis =0)
    mmt = cv2.moments(total_contour)
    if(mmt['m00'] < 7500):
        raise SmallObjectError

    self.cy = int(mmt['m10']/mmt['m00']) #y is horrizon axis
    self.cx = int(mmt['m01']/mmt['m00']) #x is vertical axis

    x, y = self.mask.shape

    adjust = m_cx - self.cx + x - temp.shape[0]
    if(adjust > 0):
        m_cx = m_cx - adjust

    temp[(m_cx-self.cx):(m_cx-self.cx) +x, (m_cy-self.cy):(m_cy-self.cy) +y] = self.mask

    self.mask = temp
```

Comment: I suspect you are *"suffering from buffering"*. I think the video data that is read from the camera is buffered and if you only read it infrequently, you may get old data that has been sitting around in buffers. One solution might be to set a lower frame rate at the start. Another might be to start a second thread/process that continuously reads the images from the camera into say 4 memory buffers cyclically and when you want a frame, you just copy the last one that this other thread filled, so that if you read say 8 frames a second, the oldest one will never  be older than 1/2 second.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thaks a lot. Can I get some reference for both solutions?

Comment: Umm, sorry, the intuitions in my head aren't indexed! ;-) Have a look around for *"Python multiprocessing"* maybe.

Comment: I don't see any `imread` in that code you pasted...

Comment: @DanMašek `imread` is not necessary. cuz `images` are scrapped directly from `cam0` by `cam0.read()`

Comment: @YYK Sure, but look at what the title of your question says... If there's no `imread` involved, then at best it's misleading.

Comment: @DanMašek Oh, You are right. It's a big mistake.

Comment: BTW, minor quirk: `frame, res = cam0.read()` you got the `frame` and `res` swapped -- the first value is a boolean flag which tells you whether you read the image. The second value is the "frame" -- the image from the video source. It's a good practice to validate that the `read` succeeded (either the first value in the tuple being true, or the second not being `None`). | Also, you show us the function `run`, but the error actually occurs in function `__resize` (line 147) called from `match` (line 184). It would really help if we could see that code and know which line is which.

Comment: @DanMašek updated code, and `match` is not really useful. So skipped that. Thanks for all pointing outs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [Mark Serchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell)'s comment. The way I am using is to set variable to `time + x seconds` and check. OpenCV have useful feature for skiping frames like `cam.grab()`. It will just read that frame from buffer but will not do anything with it. In that way you can avoid "suffering from buffering". Simple code would be:

```
import cv2
import time
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
ret,frame = cam.read()
timeCheck = time.time()
future = 10*60 # delay
while ret:
    if time.time() >= timeCheck:
        ret,frame = cam.read()
        # Do your staff here
        timeCheck = time.time()+future
    else:
        # Read from buffer, but skip it
        ret = cam.grab() # note that grab() function returnt only status code,not the frame
```

Comment: It still shows same error. I don't even know what causes the problem now. It may not because matter of `buffer`.

Comment: But it looks it solved `buffer` problem. I can't say it is the right solution, Because I'm not sure it is solved well. I'm still suffering from 'OpenCV Error'. I guess the 'OpenCV Error' is not because 'buffer' problem, but 'past image returning' was because 'buffer'.

Comment: Ok, I answered a question about past image issue (as title says). This is another problem,but I'll try to answer that as well. Most of the time, this type of error is occurred when there is no image, or there is an issue with an image. Always check for image first,then do other stuff. Try to catch errors and save that frame to disk to see if there is an issue with that frame. Save yourself a time, test this code on different cameras (Android IP camera app may be useful) and drop skip period for testing. After that, we may continue.

Comment: The issue about `buffer` is solved, thanks to your answer. And another issue I am facing is decribed here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236080/is-it-possible-same-code-returns-different-result-with-opencv  It would be helful if you join here