# How to decrease FPS of usb Camera in mechanical terms

Tags: opencv, camera, raspberry-pi, video-capture, frame-rate

I'm running project with `Raspberry-Pi`, `Python3.6`, `openCV3.4`, `V2 cam module` and `usb Camera`.(logitec c270)

When I run the code, problem is occured. Detail is described in this link.
[VideoCapture.read() returns past image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150893/videocapture-read-returns-past-image?noredirect=1#comment87348389_50150893)

Someone said that it is because both `cam` are getting kind of `VideoSignal` continuously even if image is not captured. And `Raspberry-Pi`'s computing power to read `VideoSignal` by `v4l2` codec is not enough.

In my purpose, I just need just single `image` at every minute during 3~5 hours.
I have tried this method, but didn`t work.

```
cam0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam0.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 8)
```

It looks setting `FPS` in `openCV` do not controll raw `FPS` from camera. Is there any proper way to decrease `FPS` in raw level? I can't give up the resolutions.

Comment: lower imho fps won't help because you still don't want to read each frame, so the frame buffer will still be filled with old images. Did you try to close the VideoCapture after each frame?

Comment: @Micka Do you mean `cam0.release` at the last of each loop? or closing each `VideoSignal` in buffer level?

Comment: releasing the cam after each shot

Comment: @Micka It looks that could be a solution. My coworker is gonna test that method. It takes hours to check if it is working.

Comment: @zindarod What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Your requirement is 1 image per minute. You could use a timer to raise a signal every minute for new image arrival.