# Is it possible same code returns different result with openCV?

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, mask

I'm running `python` program with `openCV` on `Raspberry-Pi`.

I got super wierd `OpenCV Error`. It looks it must not be happend, but is happened.

In short, `mask`s croped by `cv2.inRange()` is different with same `image`.

### Simple structure of my code:

1. process `images` into `mask` and calculate kind of accuracy.
2. If `mask` is not gather in (1.), which means `mask` of `image` is all black(empty) `np.array`, it skip an iteration by `exception: Value Error`
   command.(Because `min(empty np.array)` in code araise `Value Error`.)
3. Iterate (1.~2.) with time interval.

### Problem:

I've got same `OpenCV Error` more than two weeks. It is because some `parameters` in codes are assigned with wrong value. This `paramters` are mostly calculated from `mask` that is cropped from `image`. So I saved all `image`s and `mask`s in the iterating procedure. And found that there were tiny `mask` that must not be made at the `9th iteration`

Problem is that when I tired to crop `mask` with same `9 th image` manually on my labtop, it makes no `mask` which means just empty(black) `mask` is made. but there were very small `mask`(white region) is made during iterative running in `Raspberry-Pi`.

I've checked if there are difference between files in labtop and `R-Pi`, but both were same.
Here is the `images`:
First is input image to make `Real` instance. Second is manually created `mask`. Thired is Automatically created `mask` in `R-Pi`.
[image: That <code>image</code> in question][image: manually maden <code>mask</code>][image: made in R-pi <code>mask</code>]

Only difference between pc and `R-Pi` is that: when I run code manually in pc, I have used saved `image.jpg` from `SDcard of R-Pi`. and when code is run in `R-Pi` iteratively, `image` is directly captured from `R-pi camera module V2`

I know it is verry wierd, and many people would think there are typo or something wrong in codes. But I have been suffered for this problem from last two weeks. I need any thread about this kind of problem.

**Is there any possible cases that different result is gathered from same code in `openCV` or `R-pi`?**

Here is some part of code. `Real` instance is created iteratively in loop. The line occuring `OpenCV Error` is marked with `#`. If someone request, I will upload more. It is bit long to upload full code.

```
class Real:  
    __ob_low=np.array([25,100,50]) #27,65,100]) /25,100,50
    __ob_high=np.array([33,255,255]) #[45,255,255]) /33,255,255

    def __opening(self, mask):
        kernel = np.ones((7, 1), np.uint8)
        op = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
        return op

    def __init__(self, img_got,imgname):

        img = img_got
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

        mask_temp = cv2.inRange(hsv, self.__ob_low, self.__ob_high)
        mask = self.__opening(mask_temp)

        maskdir = "/home/pi/capstone/mask/" #
        img_name = imgname #
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(maskdir,img_name),mask) #

        if not (np.any(mask)):
            print("mask is empty")

        array1 = np.transpose(np.nonzero(mask))
        array2 = np.nonzero(mask)

        ymin=min(array2[1])
        ymax=max(array2[1])
        xmin=min(array2[0])
        xmax=max(array2[0])

        self.x = xmax-xmin
        self.y = ymax-ymin
        self.ratio = self.x/self.y

        self.img = img
        self.mask = mask[(xmin):(xmax),(ymin):(ymax)]
```

Comment: If I understood, the same code produces two different results on pi and pc?

Comment: @Aleksanar That is exactly right. But is looks not always produce different result on `pi`. Almost results are same with pc. But I can't guarantee that mostly same, because It is hard to trace `prameter`s and reproduce same error.

Answer (score 0):

It was because the `image` directly captured from camera is not same with `image.jpg` that is saved in disk. First one is more sensitive with `cv2.Inrange()`. It looks parts of `image` is lost during the saving process. If I have saved file as other format such as `.png` or else, result would different.

Anyway, to synchronize `R-Pi` and labtop, I have changed code to use saved `.jpg` file in both `R-Pi` and labtop.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with my code on a diffrent system and it turns out version 3.4.1 and 3.3.1 yields different result from my cropping algorithm!